# How can the ace-window hotkey be set to work in sr-speedbar?

Tags: key-bindings, hooks, speedbar

I have configured the `M-p` key to trigger `ace-window`, but when I navigate to the `sr-speedbar` window it stops working and I have to use `C-x o` to move out. Is there some mode hook I have to use to ensure that `M-p` works in `sr-speedbar` or does `sr-speedbar` use that key for something else?

```
(use-package ace-window
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :init
  (progn
    (global-set-key (kbd "M-p") 'ace-window)
    (setq aw-keys '(?a ?s ?d ?f ?g ?h ?j ?k ?l))
     ;;more info at https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window
    )
  )
```

Comment: To answer just a part of your own question "*...  or does `sr-speedbar` use that key for something else?*", the general approach is to type `C-h k` or `M-x describe-key` and then the keyboard shortcut from a particular buffer to see what function is linked to it.  [FYI:  `sr-speedbar` is a modification/tweak/add-on to the built-in `speedbar` library, rather than a completely separate animal.]

Comment: Forum participants should be aware that there is a duplicate thread on reddit:  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6rfbx2/how_can_the_acewindow_hotkey_be_set_to_work_in/?st=j5x3mu93&sh=a07e1a21

Comment: I prefer SE to reddit as SE is dedicated resource that can be archived, but questions can be closed or put on hold simply because the person asking the question doesn't know how to frame the question properly, and responses on reddit seem to be faster.

Comment: I have asked a [related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34672/what-is-considered-good-practice-for-changing-an-existing-but-unneeded-binding-t) which is a generalized version of this one.