# How to change/remove an existing but unneeded keybinding?

Tags: key-bindings

Some of the packages I use define keybindings that I want to overwrite or remove.  **How do I overwrite/remove these keybindings?**

For example, I use `ace-window` and `speedbar` together.  `ace-window` uses `M-p` for switching windows, and I want to keep that binding. However, it's used by `speedbar` for `speedbar-restricted-prev` with [`(define-key map "\M-p" 'speedbar-restricted-prev)` in the source](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/db5d38ddb0de83d8f920b7a128fe3fd5156fdf85/lisp/speedbar.el#L799)).

I don't know what `speedbar-restricted-prev` does and I don't think I will be using it. This is how I have configured `ace-window`. What else do I need to do to disable the binding of `M-p` in `speedbar`? Outside of `speedbar` it works.

```
(use-package ace-window
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :init
  (progn
    (global-set-key (kbd "M-p") 'ace-window)
    (setq aw-keys '(?a ?s ?d ?f ?g ?h ?j ?k ?l))
     ;;more info at https://github.com/abo-abo/ace-window
    ))
```

Comment: See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12385/105. Just bind the key to `nil` in the appropriate keymap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(define-key speedbar-mode-map "\M-p" nil)
```

should remove the binding of M-p from the speedbar map, so that it no longer interferes with your binding for ace-window.

You'll need to call this *after* speedbar-mode is loaded for it to have effect. Since you're using `use-package`, you can accomplish this by adding it as a `:config` option, e.g.,

```
(use-package sr-speedbar
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :config     (define-key speedbar-mode-map "\M-p" nil)
  ...)
```

More generally, you can use `eval-after-load`:

```
(eval-after-load "speedbar"
    '(define-key speedbar-mode-map "\M-p" nil))
```

Comment: [pastebin of current config[(https://pastebin.com/niciAQcc) - At what point in the cycle should the `define-key` be executed. I am aware of `add-hook` options but don't know how to use them.

Would putting the above command after the `(sr-speedbar-open)` be okay? How would I guarantee that the setting in `ace-window` would came into effect only after your `define-key` had been applied?

Comment: With this config, it doesn't matter if the `ace-window` setting comes before or after `speedbar`.